# Why does using multiple CSS files in styleUrls give me errors when using in the single home.component.html?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use multiple CSS files in `home.componenet.ts` but I am getting errors every time.  Please assist me to fix this issue.

i tried to use two approaches but with both approaches , i am getting errors.

In first approach, I am using multiple CSS files in styleUrls and in second approach, i am using multiple CSS files in `app.component.css` by importing multiple CSS files. In first approach, CSS plugin folder is under *ClientApp-> app -> assets* and in second approach, CSS plugin folder is under *wwwroot -> dist -> assets*

First approach :

following is my code

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['~/app/assets/css/style.css','~/app/assets/css/colors/green.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
    public name = 'gfggfg';
}


-- package.json

    {
  "name": "iSol",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

--- webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
            //,

            //loaders: [
            //    {
            //        test: /\.css$/,
            //        include: [
            //            path.resolve(__dirname, "not_exist_path")
            //        ],
            //        loader: "style!css"
            //    }
            //    ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.browser.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
            })
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.server.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

Second approach,

-- app.component.css

```
@import url('~/dist/assets/css/style.css');
@import url('~/dist/assets/css/colors/green.css');
@import url('~/dist/assets/css/owl.carousel.css');
@import url('~/dist/assets/css/owl.transitions.css');
@import url('~/dist/assets/css/animate.min.css');
@import url('~/dist/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

Error Description:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "./~/app/assets/css/style.css" at webpackMissingModule (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16287:86) at L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16287:191 at Object. (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16291:2) at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) at Object. (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16133:90) at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) at Object.hasOwn (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:14202:77) at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) at Object. (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16348:81) at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) Current directory is: L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()

When i am removing ~/ then application is throwing following errors. please see

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "-!../../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./dist/assets/css/style.css"
at webpackMissingModule (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16390:75)
at Object. (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16390:226)
at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at Object. (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:17967:22)
at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10401:22
at Object. (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10405:2)
at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at Object. (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16131:88)
at **webpack_require** (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
Current directory is: L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore

Comment: Could you give us the errors you're getting please? Does your app compile and run or not?

Comment: yes please see above , i have added in above post now

Comment: @Kapcash in error message  final css path is ./~/app/assets/css/style.css .it should work by removing  '~/'

Comment: please see above. i have added the exception by removing ~/

Comment: Try to remove the '~/' in style url array. Angular (cli) try to resolve paths from node_module and your root app directory, you do not need to use the home shortcut ~.

Comment: getting this error : An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "-!../../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./dist/assets/css/style.css"
at webpackMissingModule (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16391:75)
at Object.<anonymous> (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16391:226)
at __webpack_require__ (L:\SaleStore\iSaleStore\iSaleStore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
a